# Why won't my nav be 100% in width relative to the browser

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav, fluid-layout

If you test out this code and resized the browser window, the last list-item "sign up" when hovered (is the only way to tell) that it doesn't stretch 100%. I've tried many different ways. If someone can test it out and find a solution; please explain how you fixed it that way I can learn. Please.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(182, 182, 182, 1);
}
div.main_container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("../images/IMG_0060.JPG");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
div.nav_container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 700px;
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, .75);
}
ul.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.nav li {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 12.5%;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.nav li marquee {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: fantasy;
}
ul.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: fantasy;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: lightgray;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul.nav li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(205, 205, 205, .50);
}
ul.nav li:hover marquee {
  background-color: black;
  color: lightgreen;
}
ul.nav li:hover a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <title>Kendall's Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main_container">
    <div class="nav_container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">kendall</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">social</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">tutorials</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <marquee scrollamount="2">
            some sliding text
          </marquee>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">login</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">sign up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--Closing of the nav-->
    </div>
    <!--Closing of the nav_container-->
  </div>
  <!--Closing of the main_container-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's because of the `table` property of `li` and `a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `last-child` of `ul.nav li` to `float:right`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(182, 182, 182, 1);
}
div.main_container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("../images/IMG_0060.JPG");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
div.nav_container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 700px;
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, .75);
}
ul.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.nav li {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 12.5%;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.nav li:last-child {
  float:right;  
}
ul.nav li marquee {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: fantasy;
}
ul.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: fantasy;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: lightgray;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul.nav li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(205, 205, 205, .50);
}
ul.nav li:hover marquee {
  background-color: black;
  color: lightgreen;
}
ul.nav li:hover a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <title>Kendall's Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main_container">
    <div class="nav_container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">kendall</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">social</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">tutorials</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <marquee scrollamount="2">
            some sliding text
          </marquee>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">login</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">sign up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--Closing of the nav-->
    </div>
    <!--Closing of the nav_container-->
  </div>
  <!--Closing of the main_container-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Omg.. Thank you so much! That was .. Quite obvious I didn't even think about it. THANK YOU!!

Comment: My pleasure ;) Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer sp it will help to other people.